# Pinescript storing high and low value's error

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to simulate a relatively basic trading strat but unfortunately my attempts aren't working.

In essence, when there is a red candle, you buy whenever the next candle close is above that red candle's high. This buy price is constantly shifting to the next lower high as the next red candle makes a close beneath the original red candle's low. Any movement inside the candle's low and high is therefore ignored. After an entry is made, you then sell whenever the next candle is below the low of the candle you purchased at. This again continuously shift up as new and higher green candles are made.

```
//@version=4

strategy("9gag", pyramiding = 1, overlay=true)
candlehigh = 0.0
candlelow = 0.0
var bool enable = false


if ( close < open and enable == false )
    candlehigh := high
    candlelow := low
    enable := true
    
if (enable == true and close < candlelow)
    candlehigh := high
    candlelow := low
    enable := true

if (close > candlehigh and enable == true )
    strategy.entry("long",strategy.long,1.0,when = close > candlehigh)
    enable := false
    
if (close < candlelow and enable == true)
    strategy.close("long", when = close < candlelow)
    enable := false
```

So the way I'm trying to get this to work is if the close < open, then I'd like to store the high and low values of that candle in "candlehigh" and "candlelow" respectively. I have a boolean enable to prevent that sequence of logic from running again until an entry is made.

then the next block of code checks to see if a lower close has been made since the last time the low of the last candle was recorded from the previous block of code. If this is true, then the lows and highs of the most recent bar are again recorded.

After that, an entry is made whenever a bar closes above the last recorded candlehigh.

enable is made false so this can repeat.

Right now the code is spitting back any errors at me, but no trades are being placed so it doesn't appear to be working.

I can't find any reason why this shouldn't work, any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should accomplish what you are trying to do. Instead of structuring the way you have, I've tracked whether you are in a long or not. Keep in mind orders are executed on the open of the next bar from the signal. Green arrows represent the bar where the condition to enter occurred, the red x where the condition was met to close the position.

We use `barstate.isconfirmed` to check the conditions right on the closing of the current bar. To keep it cleaner, I've separated the logic from the entry/close commands by using bool variables `enter_long` and `exit_long`. We can then also use these boolean variables to `plotshape()` to visually check the logic. If you have additional conditions you want to add later you can either use the same bool to flip the one entry command or have multiple different bools for each type of entry condition ie `enter_x_long` or `enter_y_long` etc. When things inevitably don't work as planned having `plotshape()` mapping out your different conditions will make it a lot easier to debug.

It can also be helpful when coding these kinds of things to plot your levels like candlehigh to debug.

```
var float candlehigh = na
var float candlelow = na

var bool in_a_long = false
bool enter_long = false
bool exit_long = false

if barstate.isconfirmed
    if in_a_long == false
        if close < open
            candlehigh := high
            candlelow := low
        else if close > open and close > candlehigh and close[1] < open[1]
            candlehigh := high
            in_a_long := true
            enter_long := true
    else if in_a_long == true
        if close < open
            if close < candlelow
                in_a_long := false
                exit_long := true
                candlehigh := high
                candlelow := low
            else if close > candlelow and low > candlelow
                candlelow := low
        else if close > open and low > candlelow
            candlelow := low
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, 1.0, when = enter_long)
    strategy.close("long", when = exit_long)

plot(candlehigh, color = color.lime)
plot(candlelow, color = color.red)
plotshape(enter_long, style = shape.triangleup, location = location.belowbar, color = color.lime, size = size.small)
plotshape(exit_long, style = shape.xcross, location = location.abovebar, color = color.red, size = size.small)
```